# Configure project :react-native-reanimated

Tags: react-native

Configure project :react-native-reanimated

---

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'D:\Projects\Vow\iye_react_native_user_app\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\build.gradle' line: 152
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-reanimated'.

> Could not get unknown property 'rnMinorVersion' for project ':react-native-reanimated' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'D:\Projects\Vow\iye_react_native_user_app\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\build.gradle' line: 152
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-reanimated'.

> Could not get unknown property 'rnMinorVersion' for project ':react-native-reanimated' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14s

```
at makeError (D:\Projects\Vow\iye_react_native_user_app\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at D:\Projects\Vow\iye_react_native_user_app\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (D:\Projects\Vow\iye_react_native_user_app\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
at async Command.handleAction (D:\Projects\Vow\iye_react_native_user_app\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:192:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Install version 2.9.0 or above to fixed this issue:
"react-native-reanimated": "^2.9.1"

Comment: upgraded reanimated version 2.9.1 but issue not solved

Comment: @Prasad upgrading to 2.17.0 worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Rename $minor to $rnMinorVersionCopy in the android/build.gradle file of react-native-reanimated folder in node_modules. That is my solution for now until they update the library with a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Check this thread
https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/3319
It's already been reported

Answer (score 0):

Please update your package

Follow these steps

- npm i react-native-reanimated
- go to your project folder and   cd android ->  ./gradlew clean ->
- Run Your project npm start --reset-cache
- npx react-native run-android